# Installing Linux from an external card reader

Tags: linux, boot, sd-card, sdhc, installation-media

I have this problem. I was experimenting if I could use a memory card ([SDHC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#SDHC)) as an USB drive for all intents and purposes, and when I put the card in an USB card reader, I can use it just like a regular USB stick, and it also shows up in the BBS popup menu as an USB stick. When I tried to create an installation media out of it like this:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/image of=/dev/sdb
```

And tried to boot from it, simply nothing happened. Cursor blinked a couple of times, and jumped to the [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) of my pre-existing GNU/Linux installation. What am I missing here? Is this not doable?

I tried this with [Xubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu) 12.04 and [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux), by the way. I have also tried `UNetBootIn` instead of `dd`. Nothing happened differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is related to the BIOS of your PC, if the BIOS supports a driver for your card reader then it will load data from it and boot, otherwise it will load nothing from it..